# Dates in Cassandra appear rounded when imported from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, cassandra

I am importing data from SQL Server (2016) into Cassandra. In SQL Server, the dates include the millisecond. BUT in Cassandra they are rounded up or down to the half-millisecond like:

```
2016-02-14 06:43:30-0500
```

whereas in SQL Server it is:

```
2016-02-14 11:43:30.950
```

I have tried:

```
  string date = "'" + reader.GetDateTime(column).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffZ") + "'";
```

as well as:

```
  DateTime dt = reader.GetDateTime(column);            
  double timespace = dt.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMilliseconds;
```

with the same results.

(I haven't accounted for time zones which I assume accounts for the 5 hour difference)

Comment: Whats your schema? what type are you using to store the dates? Probably has more to do with how your reading/displaying it since a timestamp is a "64-bit signed integers representing a number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as the epoch".

Comment: Yes, it somehow relates to how they are displayed in Datastax DevCenter. When I ran the query in the CQL Shell, they data returns correct. THANKS!